# Remove value from state (set new state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove a value from my state.

I am using `.filter` as I believe this is the simplest way of doing it. I also want to implement an `undo` function ( but that's outside the scope of this question).

I have put this code in a sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/yrwo2PZ2R

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: x.movies,
    };
  }
remove = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('remove movie.id:', e.target.value)
  const index = e.target.value
  this.setState({
    movies: this.state.movies.filter((_, e) => e.id !== index)
  });
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.movies.map(e =>
          <div key={e.id}>
            <li>{e.name}  {e.id}</li>
            <button value={e.id} onClick={this.remove}>remove</button>
          </div>,
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

First of all, the index you're getting from the event target value is a string, but you're comparing against a number. Change the index declaration as follows:

```
const index = Number(e.target.value);
```

Secondly, your filter is a little off. This will work:

```
this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.id !== index)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `index` has string type, but id in objects has `number` type. You need type cast, for example:

```
const index = Number(e.target.value);
```

Other than that, you have some wrong `_` in callback of `filter` function call. You don't need it. You need:

```
this.state.movies.filter(e => e.id !== index)
```

By the way I don't recommend to name values this way. Why `e`? You have array of movies. Use `movie`. Why `index`? You have id to remove. Then use `idToRemove` name.

You also have problem with adding items.

Firstly, you can add items like this:

```
this.setState({
  movies: [...this.state.movies, { name: item.value.name, id: item.value.id }],
})
```

Another point: you have to autoincrement id. You can store last value in a variable. `this.idCounter` for example. And add will look like:

```
this.setState({
  movies: [...this.state.movies, { name: item.value.name, id: this.idCounter++ }],
})
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vMJQ3p5M

Comment: Could you show me in the code sandbox? I was . not able to apply your example. https://codesandbox.io/s/yrwo2PZ2R . I thought it was line 52 that added it which is ` this.props.addItem(this.state);`

Comment: I updated answer again, so now it is full (you must not accept it, because @SamHH answer was first). I added some suggestions about variable names + it has part about adding elements.

Comment: Another way to achieve what you want is `not strict equality`. But I am not sure it is good idea to use it. It is much more implicit. Thats not good.

Comment: Also, I am not sure that it is good idea to store id counter like I did. Maybe better place to store it is the store of your component.

Comment: UPDATE: THIS COMMENT PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE FIXED [Something odd is happening with your example in `this.setState({ title: '' });`  line 50. If I press enter, it remembers the value from before (IE but it should be a blank string). https://codesandbox.io/s/QWR1D3wM0.]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in the following manner

```
remove = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('remove movie.id:', e.target.value)
  const index = e.target.value
  var movies = [...this.state.movies]
  var idx = movies.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === parseInt(index))
  movies.splice(idx, 1);

  this.setState({
    movies
  });
}
```

Also use parseInt to convert index to a string before comparing.
Directly setting the current state from the previous state values can cause problems  as setState is asynchronous. You should ideally create a copy of the object and delete the object using splice method

**[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/G6Dy71gq5)**

Comment: That tells me `findIndex` is not a function. Could you try it in the example? https://codesandbox.io/s/yrwo2PZ2R

Comment: Nope. That is deleting the bottom item (not the specific item I click)

Comment: Not sure that it is good way to solve the problem. I mean use `==` instead of `===`. Type cast is much more obvious solution. And there is lesser probability to make error on refactoring if you have explicit type cast.